# Assembly: Branching

Tags: string, assembly, branch

In my code below, I am taking a string and creating a copy that changes the lowercase letters to uppercase.  For some reason, when I run the code, it only gets through the first word, "This", and then stops.

I thought the 'space' isn't 'null' and should continue branching.

```
        ORG $5000
data:   dc.b "This is a Test String", 0
        ORG $4000
        ldx #data
        ldy #$5020
loop:   ldaa 1,X+
        anda #$5F
        staa 1,Y+
        bne loop
        bgnd
```

Comment: Explain from where you got #$5F.

Comment: #$5F in binary is #1011111, so ANDing it, will clear the bit if it is lowercase, therefore switching it to uppercase.

Comment: Is *space* lowercase?

Comment: @JensBjörnhager: You're right.  Space is #$20, which ANDing with #$5F would be zero.  That's why it is branching.

Comment: Bingo! Wrote up an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is exited because you are not comparing the `space`, but the `space` anded with `#$5F`, which IS `null`.